# Saying words in a given language in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

How can Python be used to say words in a given language?

When I tried this:

```
import os

os.system("say 'hi'")
```

Python displayed:

```
sh: 1: say: not found
```

When I tried this:

```
import pyttsx3;

engine = pyttsx3.init();
engine.say("I will speak this text");
engine.runAndWait();
```

Python said that there was no such file/directory as `libespeak.so.1` while running the `__init__()`.

At last, I tried:

```
import win32com.client as wincl

speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.Speak("This is the pc voice speaking")
```

Python told me that there was no such thing as `win32com`.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx/1.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing pypiwin32

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

This is for

```
import win32com.client as wincl
speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.Speak("This is the pc voice speaking")
```

Comment: This is for the 'win32com.client' one

Comment: I haven't imported pip on my computer. Can you show me how to do it? My computer is a Mac OS windows 10.

Comment: ```import pip
pip install pypiwin32
import win32com.client as wincl
speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.Speak("This is the pc voice speaking")```